# Preview app automatically switching tabs?

Tags: macos, mac, preview, big-sur

I recently updated to Big Sur. When I have multiple tabs of pdf files opened in Preview app, the app is automatically switching between tabs. I have never noticed this before, how do I stop it?

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue!